# What does the bitwise operator & do in this example?

Tags: arrays, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, mql4

This example is from MQL4 but that doesn't really matter:

```
int OnCalculate( const int       rates_total,
                 const int       prev_calculated,
                 const datetime &time[],
                 const double   &open[],
                 const double   &high[],
                 const double   &low[],
                 const double   &close[],
                 const long     &tick_volume[],
                 const long     &volume[],
                 const int      &spread[]
                 )
```

What does matter is that I don't understand what the bitwise operator **`&`** is telling me here.

I know what happens if you have 2 variables and use it `var1 && var2` but in this situation with an array, could someone help me out here?

Comment: It's not bitwise and, it's the [address-of operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&`in the argument indicates [pass-by reference](http://docs.mql4.com/basis/function/parameterpass) and not bitwise and. Passing by reference as opposed to pass-by value means that the argument value isn't copied, instead it's the address to the data structure that is copied and passed in to the function.

**Edit**: see @Sneftel's comment below about pass-by reference

Comment: Nitpick: The `&` does not technically indicate pass-by-reference (there's no such thing in the language), but that the variable being passed *is a reference*. The difference can be seen in the fact that the variable type inside the function is treated as a reference type, not as a non-reference type.

Comment: @Sneftel Good catch, I'll edit the answer and point to your comment.